# How to stop autoplay of videos in Epic Games Launcher?

Tags: epic-games-launcher

Since the beginning of this game client's life there is a significant performance drop when the user opens the page of game X - the main trailer or next gameplay video automatically starts playing. Wasted MBs/GBs of traffic, sometimes this hiccups the whole machine. Already asked their support and the only thing I received was a greeting for playing Chapter 2 of Fortnite ... *I never played Fortnite and still won't do it*

Any idea how to stop the autoplay?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is (still) not possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the gear in the bottom right corner of a video. This opens a pane with the option to disable autoplay on all videos within EGS.

[image: Example]